# Actual life expectancy of COTS power supplies

Tags: power-supply, power, lifetime

Can anyone shed some light on what the actual expected lifetime of a commercial off-the-shelf power supply would be?  I've seen the unbelievable MTBF numbers given in power supply datasheets, and found out fairly quickly that they're a bit of a scam; they don't refer to the actual “mean time between failures” of the power supplies, but are only the inverse of the failure rate early in the life of the power supplies (at the bottom of the bath-tub curve).  What would be more useful to know is the time at which the failure rate starts to rise significantly (and hence “MTBF” has fallen to something meaningful), or maybe the time at which 50% of the power supplies could be expected to have failed.

Comment: What kind of power supply? I've seen MIL-Spec power supplies with very realistic MTBF. I've also run across Chinese knock off supplies that fail reliably after just weeks.

Comment: @RonBeyer -- "fail reliably", not sure if funny or sad.. :D

Comment: @WesleyLee Funny when your purchasing agent says "I saved you $25", sad when you have to explain to them why it actually costs twice as much (having to buy the Chinese one the first time, and the spec'd one the second time).

Comment: I was looking at a 5Vdc power supply, say similar to TDK-Lambda RWS300B-5, which shows a MTBF of over 2,000,000 hours, or over 200 years.  The warranty time of 7 years is more realistic, but probably too conservative.  If I advise buying 2000 of these for a 50 year project, I'd like to know when to advise they will need to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Without a **HALT or QALT** (highly or quality accelerated life test) approach to testing, there is **no way** to accurately assess the long-term reliability of a product in a short time that defines MTBF.

The only way to prove an expected life is to test it for that duration in a nominal environmental.  One can establish a Confidence Level of a failure rate based on FITs or MTBF and time, but only time is give 100% confidence in a result.

Stress to reduce the time and measuring margin to failure is the best way to devise a product Design Verification Test or DVT plan.

It also requires an **Ongoing Reliability Test** (ORT) to ensure the quality does not change.

These methods require skill to determine the type and amount of environmental level stress and Arrhenius acceleration rates.

e.g. a "constant" failure rate of  0.25% per year is an MTBF of 400 yrs  but the MTTR could be 10 yrs or <1 yr if used improperly.